# HTML5 camera live streaming ASP.NET MVC C#

Tags: file, video, stream, live

I am trying to make something like the live camera option in Facebook for my web application project using MVC5/ASP.NET C#. I just happened to stumble on the video tag like `"input type="file" accept="video/*;capture=camcorder"`. But I wonder how I can stream a live video using the above tag to a remote browser or a mobile app. Any ideas? Doesn't matter if in any other way or are there any plugin that's available?